# ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync() returning different results

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Long story short, a stored procedure in cosmosDB is returning 2 when executed inside the portal, and is returning 0 when called from `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync()` in my c# console app.
The correct response is 2

Here's the stored procedure:

JS:

```
function countItems() {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    var query = "SELECT * FROM c";

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collectionLink,
        query,
        function(err, documents, responseOptions) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            response.setBody(documents.length);
        }
    );
}
```

When I run this from the azure portal, it returns the correct result: 2.

/////////////////////

Here's the C# call:

C#

```
private static async Task ExecuteStoredProc(string spId, CosmosContext cosmosContext)
{
    using (var client = new CosmosClient(cosmosContext.Endpoint, cosmosContext.MasterKey))
    {
        var container = client.GetContainer(cosmosContext.DbId, cosmosContext.ContainerId);
        var scripts = container.Scripts;
        var pk = new PartitionKey(cosmosContext.DbId);
        var result = await scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(spId, pk, null);
        var message = result.Resource;

        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

When I run this from the C# console app, it returns 0

What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, you may not set the `PartitionKey` correctly.

If you have set partition key, you need to pass the correct partition key.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new CosmosClient(Endpoint, Key))
    {
        // With Partition Key
        var container = client.GetContainer("TestDB", "Demo");

        var scripts = container.Scripts;

        // With Partition Key
        var pk = new PartitionKey("B");
        var result =scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("length", pk, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var message = result.Resource;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

[image]

If there is no partition key, then you need to pass `PartitionKey.None`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new CosmosClient(Endpoint, Key))
    {
        // Without Partition Key
        var container = client.GetContainer("ToDoList", "Items");

        var scripts = container.Scripts;

        //Without Partition Key
        var result = scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("length", PartitionKey.None, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var message = result.Resource;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

[image]